# Linear functional norm

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

We are given $T:l_2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $T({x_n})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}x_{3n}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}x_{2n}$. I would like to know what the norm of that functional is and if (I suppose it is but have troubles proving that) it is always convergent ?

**EDIT:** afther some time of thinking I thought that in fact we may make that question a little more theoretic, precisely: what condition/s does the seccuence $\{y_n\}$ have to satysfie in order to functional $T:l_2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $T({x_n})=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_ny_n$ would be continious, and what the norm is than?

(maby [I doubt it because than the previou one would be divergent, but as far as I know there can't be written down explicitly not bounded functional on complete space] $\{y_n\}$ must be in $l_2$?)

Comment: The (topological) dual of $l_2$ can be identified with $l_2$ in the sense that $T$ is a continuous (i.e., bounded) linear functional on $l_2$ if and only if there exists a sequence $(y_n)$ in $l_2$ such that $T(x_n)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x_ny_n$ for any $(x_n)\in l_2$. Hence, the mapping from the first line is not a bounded linear functional. Note that actually that mapping is not defined for every $(x_n)\in l_2$.

Comment: You are right I actually  was able to handle it finally myself, afther all during last classes I was told that the functional from $l_p$ given by series convolution is well defined iff the sequence defying it is from $l_q$ where q is as alwasy $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$